# I want to start a new activity by clicking on my layout what should i do?

Tags: android

I had created four different layout that has a different function and now i want  to start a new intent or a new activity by clicking on that layout.

I had set button methods  on my layout and started a new intent but its not working what should i do to satrt my activity.

Comment: I have posted the suggested steps for your reference. If that does not help, please edit your question to provide your attempted code and the error you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the suggested steps to achieve your purpose:

#### Step 1

Check in your **AndroidManifest.xml** what is the launching Activity. It should be the Activity with `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`:

```xml
...
    <activity
        android:name=".menupage"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

In the above example, it should be your `menupage` Activity class. (Assuming that you are only able to start the App and launch the default Activity currently)

#### Step 2

You should assign ID to your 4 layouts. And also can try to set `clickable` and `focusable` of the Layout to true. And you can retrieve them from your Activity class later on:

```xml
<...
    android:id="@+id/layoutA
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    ...>

<...
    android:id="@+id/layoutB
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    ...>

<...
    android:id="@+id/layoutC"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    ...>

<...
    android:id="@+id/layoutD"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    ...>
```

#### Step 3

To set click event listener, you should use the following function:

```java
findViewById(R.id.layoutA).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TAG", "I have pressed Layout A!");
        // Implement function when you click on Layout A
    }
});
```

#### Step 4

You should use the following approach to trigger another Activity:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityForLayoutA.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Step 5

Make sure you have registered the corresponding Activity in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```xml
<application
    ...>
    ...
    <activity android:name=".ActivityForLayoutA" />
</application>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working actually. That's why I need help.

Comment: Does the App crash? Can you provide more details about **not working actually**? If possible, it is better for you to provide your implemented code, at least the way that you **set button methods on my layout and started a new intent**.

Comment: electrician.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               selectedService="electrician";
                 Intent myintent = new Intent(menupage.this,electrician_page.class);
                 startActivity(myintent);'

Comment: The app is not crashing its simply not working when I am clicking on the layout.

Comment: Can you show how you set ```electrician```? Does it match with your layout ID? You can try to add log in the ```onClick()``` function to see if it passes through it when you click on your targeted Layout.

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/electricianlayout"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="162dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

Comment: LinearLayout electricianlayout;                                                                                                     electricianlayout =findViewById(R.id.electricianlayout);

Comment: Seems that there is nothing wrong about that. Can you follow my edited Step 2 and see if there is any output in logcat? I doubt that the one you are pressing may not be ```electrician```.

Comment: The log is not showing anything,i think the onclick listner is not working.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with your ```setOnClickListener```. Are you sure you are pressing on the correct view? If your layout is *invisible* and with this ```android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="162dp"``` size, you may not be pressing on the view as what you think.

Comment: Yes i am pressing the correct layout layout has balck background , actually i had tried pressing all the layout none of the m is working.

Comment: I see that you are having menupage Activity. Can you follow my edited Step 1 and confirm if the default launching Activity points to menupage not other Activity? And also can you try on the 2 attributes in Step 2?